# java: error while loading shared libraries: libjl i.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: java, debian, raspberry-pi

I've researched this and tried everything. Running Debian on a Raspberry Pi.

Trying to run java and getting this error:

```
"/home/pi/java/ejre1.7.0_21/bin/java: error while loading shared libraries: libjli.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
```

I need someone to help me troubleshoot this.

1. Added path variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH
2. Copied libjli.so all over creation
3. don't know what else to do.

Comment: There's also http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ for general raspi stuff

Answer (score 1):

It will never work on that version of Debian, see [this](http://sumedha.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/getting-oracle-jvm-to-run-in-raspberry.html).

If you must run 1.7 you'll need a soft-float OS, otherwise try the [1.8 preview release](https://jdk8.java.net/fxarmpreview/javafx-arm-developer-preview.html) which is hard-float.